# Is there another way to prove that the electric field inside of a conductor is 0 without using Gauss' law?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Suppose there is a spherical shell conductor with a stationary negative charge placed inside. The shell has finite thickness so in order to make the field inside of the conductor 0, positive charge equal to the magnitude of the negative charge needs to be induced on the inner surface of the shell so that the charge enclosed within a Gaussian sphere inside of the metal of the conducting shell will be equal to zero (and thus the field through that Gaussian surface will also be zero). Is there another way to prove the fact that the electric field within the conductor will eventually become 0? I was trying to use Coulomb's law but was stuck on how to justify the fact that the inner surface of the shell will be induced with a charge equal to that of the negative charge inside of it. Intuitively, it seems like the positive charges would distribute to make the centers of the negative and positive charges coincide.

Comment: You did not use Gauss' law to prove that the field is zero. You used the fact that the field is zero to show that the induced charge is equal to the charge inside the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Gauss' law is one of the laws governing electromagnetism. I don't think you can describe behavior of electromagnetic fields without these laws - they *define* them.

It helps to state what you mean by conductor. At this level, it probably means that inside the conductor current density ($\mathbf{J}$) is proportional to electric field ($\mathbf{J}$), i.e. $\mathbf{J}=\sigma\cdot\mathbf{E}$, where $\sigma$ is the [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity). This is known as [constitutive equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation#Electromagnetism). Basically it defines what you mean by conductor. At this point you could do one of two things. You could say that equilibrium position is one where no current is flowing, so electric field, for finite conductivity, must be zero by definition. Another approach is to derive the wave equation and to show that presence of conductivity will lead to dissipation, i.e. in the long-term electric field will go to zero.

If this is not a suitable way forward, it helps to state clearly what you mean by conductor.

If this is a suitable way forward, you basically have a prescription: conductor+statics = zero electric field inside the conductor. The rest, like surface charge, then fits around this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer your question, would be to consider what would happen if two points in a conductive surface were not equipotential i.e. had an electric field
$\vec{E}_0$ (due to the stationary negative charge $-q_0$) directed from one to the other. Electrons would flow opposite to this electric field and cause charge build-up at these points. These charges would have their own electric field between them (say $\vec{E'}$).

Now the only way this flow of charges stops (equilibrium is attained), is if the net electric field between these two points is $\vec{0}$ which gives us
$$\vec{E_{net}}=\vec{E_0}+\vec{E'}=\vec{0}\implies \vec{E'}=-\vec{E_0}$$
which implies that the equilibrium state is where the redistributed electrons in the conductor exactly cancel out the external electric field.

Now from Newton's Shell Theorem we know that any symmetric spherical distribution of charge behaves exactly as if it were concentrated at the centre (when it's effect is considered outside the sphere), which allows us to use $\vec{E'}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{in}}{r^2}\hat{r}$ where $q_{in}$ represents the charge on the inner surface of the shell, $r$ represents the radius of the inner surface of the shell and $\hat{r}$ represents a radial unit vector from the centre to the point at which the field is being considered (this point is just beyond the inner surface of the shell).

We now have a simple calculation,
$$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{in}}{r^2}\hat{r}=-\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{-q_0}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
$$\implies q_{in} = q_0 $$

---

Note that this is exactly what Gauss' Law also tells you, which is the fact that the net charge inside the spherical Gaussian surface ($q_{in}-q_0$) is $0$.